# how to style dots in slick-slider without style slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I stylize the dots with class .slick-active, my carousel background stylized too. How I can remove background from slides and have background in dots-active?

```
.slick-active{
    width: 1.333rem;
    height: 1.333rem;
    background: #23aae2;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.comment__choise li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.333rem;
    height: 1.333rem;
    border: 0.067rem dashed #23aae2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.single-item').slick({
dots: true,
dotsClass: 'comment__choise > li',
infinite: false,
});
});
```

[image]

I decide my problem with next code

```
.slick-active{
width: 1.333rem;
height: 1.333rem;
background: #23aae2;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.slick-current{
background: #fff;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHclF.png)

Comment: Just limit it to the correct parent element ... `.slick-dots .slick-active { … }`

Answer (score 0):

I cant figure out with the given information how the big div is getting the style applied for dots but you may try adding this,

```
#slick-slide00, #slick-slide01, #slick-slide02, {
background: #fff;
border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's don't work. Or maybe I doing something wrong?!